# Why add-migration command is giving error although build succeeds in Visual Studio using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-2.0

I'm new to .NET and keep getting the following error when executing `add-migration` command in Visual Studio 2022.
[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYVRv.png)

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: C:\Users\myname\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.1\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\

The following frameworks were found:
  3.1.32 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  5.0.17 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  6.0.16 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  7.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

Notice,
`App: C:\Users\myName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.1\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll`
does not point to the location of my solution/project but to some nuget package.

`.csproj` file mentions `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`. So I assume my app is using .NET `3.1` which is already installed in my system. But the error says I should have .NET `2.0.0`

I tried to check the .NET version in package manager console.
`PM> dotnet --version`
`7.0.203`

I genuinely appreciate any fixes or help in understanding why its asking for `2.0.0` when my app uses `3.1` and why its showing `7.0` when I try to check the version in PM Console.

Comment: Check the Target.  Your target is set to Core 7.0 which is the latest.  I'm not sure if migration will work with older versions of Net Core.  Make sure you do clean build to remove intermediate obj files and entire project gets rebuilt.  The reason for Net 3.1 would be if your obj are not getting compiled or the Target is set to Net 3.1.

Comment: You can check what is the target framework of your project in project properties? If it does not match your entityframeworkcore compatible version, update entityframeworkcore or change the target framework

Answer (score 0):

```
PM> dotnet --version
7.0.203
```

What this command says is the latest version of .NET you have installed on your system, not what your project uses.

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

While this already indicates that your app is using .NET Core 3.1, if you want to use .NET 7 you should swap it for

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
```

After that I'd update the nuget packages to corresponding versions and try again.